# More formal alternative for “get a handle on sth.”

Tags: phrase-requests, formality

In a text I am writing (paper in the sciences), I find I would like to use the phrase “In order to get a handle on this problem, …”, but it seems a little informal.

The intended meaning is “gain a better understanding of the problem, and, if possible, solve it”.  (As it turns out, “the problem” is not completely solved in my paper.)

What would be a phrase appropriate for the rather formal context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like either:

“[In order to [better] address the problem](https://books.google.com/books?id=QF2QAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA60&dq=%22in+order+to+better+address+the+problem%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCMQ6AEwAWoVChMIhOTMwL6FxgIVkSWMCh2DtAdV#v=onepage&q=%22in%20order%20to%20better%20address%20the%20problem%22&f=false)”

or

“[In order to confront the problem [head-on]](https://books.google.com/books?id=FdvEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA343&dq=%22in+order+to+confront+the+problem%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAGoVChMI_6mFur-FxgIV0DGMCh34aADW#v=onepage&q=%22in%20order%20to%20confront%20the%20problem%22&f=false)"

Comment: Not that I would say there is a single "right" answer here, but I am going with *confront*.  Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going **to look into** this problem carefully and try to find the best solution.

> - look into -  check into something; see into something Fig. to investigate something. [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/look+into)

e.g. "I'll have to look into that matter personally and find a solution."

Answer (score 0):

I think ***to deal with*** (something) may fit your contesxt:

> - to take action to do something, especially to solve a problem
>     -The government must now deal with the problem of high unemployment.

(Macmillan Dict.)

Comment: I kinda think *deal with* in this sense isn't quite formal enough.  Perhaps simply, *in order to understand this problem*, *in order to fully comprehend this problem*, *in order to successfully approach this problem*

Answer (score 0):

The following may serve.  Parentheses denote optional text.  Square braces mean 'pick one'

> "In order to more fully understand the problem (domain), and thereby [derive/synthesize/posit] a solution, or [at least mitigation/to at least mitigate the symptom(s)], ..."